# SQL table doesn't exist error even though it does

Tags: mysql, django, django-celery

When I run 'show tables' in mysql, I get these:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Tables                              |
+-------------------------------------+
| ...                                 |
| djcelery_crontabschedule            |
| djcelery_intervalschedule           |
| djcelery_periodictask               |
| djcelery_periodictasks              |
| djcelery_taskstate                  |
| djcelery_workerstate                |
| ...                                 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

The 'djcelery_periodictask' is clearly shown and when running:

`select * from <any_of_the_above_tables>`

it works and successfully prints empty set or the data.

But, for only the "djcelery_periodictask" table, I am getting a table doesn't exist error even though it clearly does as shown from the show tables command.

Does anyone know why I am having this problem?

I am running both both django celery 3.1.17 and celery 3.1.17.

Comment: Can you access the `djcelery_periodictask` table via a query directly in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: nope :( same error

Comment: Are you sure that this table even exists?  Do you get any error in Workbench?

Comment: Well the table definitely shows up when I run "show tables", and when trying to select * from the table in either the workbench or mysql shell, it says the table doesn't exist

Comment: do a restart `sudo service mysql-server restart` may solve

Comment: Check your DATABASES settings.